# How to add a PatternLayout to the root logger at runtime?

Tags: java, logging, logback

I am using logback as the backend for Slf4j. Currently, I configure the logger using a `logback.xml` file. My issue is that sensitive information is being logged (outside of my control) and I want to mask this sensitive information. To mask the information, I have wrote a custom `PatternLayout` class that essentially does:

```
@Override
public String doLayout(ILoggingEvent event) {
    String message = super.doLayout(event);
    Matcher matcher = sesnsitiveInfoPattern.matcher(message);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        message = matcher.replaceAll("XXX");
    }
    return message;
}
```

My issue is that I need to tell logback to use this custom pattern layout. I don't want to add this to the XML configuration however. My current configuration looks like this:

```
<configuration> 
  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender"> 
    <encoder>
      <layout class="com.my.MaskingPatternLayout"> <!-- here -->
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
      </layout>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

In XML, my desired configuration would look like this (but I don't want to use XML):

Answer (score 1):

Hello Max I hope you are using Log4j 2.x because this solution uses the plugins approache introduced in log4j 2.x . first you should create a package where you are going to put your plugins classes and you put there these two classes :

my.log4j.pluggins.CustomConfigurationFactory :

```
@Plugin(name = "CustomConfigurationFactory", category = ConfigurationFactory.CATEGORY)
    @Order(value = 0)
    public class CustomConfigurationFactory extends ConfigurationFactory {

        private Configuration createConfiguration(final String name,
                ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder) {
            System.out.println("init logger");
            builder.setConfigurationName(name);
            builder.setStatusLevel(Level.INFO);
            builder.setPackages("my.log4j.pluggins");
            AppenderComponentBuilder appenderBuilder = builder.newAppender(
                    "Stdout", "CONSOLE").addAttribute("target",
                    ConsoleAppender.Target.SYSTEM_OUT);
            appenderBuilder
                    .add(builder
                            .newLayout("PatternLayout")
                            .addAttribute("pattern", "%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %myMsg%n"));
            builder.add(appenderBuilder);
            builder.add(builder.newRootLogger(Level.TRACE).add(
                    builder.newAppenderRef("Stdout")));
            return builder.build();
        }

        @Override
        protected String[] getSupportedTypes() {
            String[] supportedExt = { "*" };
            return supportedExt;

        }

        @Override
        public Configuration getConfiguration(ConfigurationSource source) {
            ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder = newConfigurationBuilder();
            return createConfiguration(source.toString(), builder);
        }

        @Override
        public Configuration getConfiguration(String name, URI configLocation) {
            ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder = newConfigurationBuilder();
            return createConfiguration(name, builder);
        }

    }
```

my.log4j.pluggins.SampleLayout  :

```
    @Plugin(name = "CustomConverter", category = "Converter")
    @ConverterKeys({"myMsg"})
    public class SampleLayout extends LogEventPatternConverter {

        protected SampleLayout(String name, String style) {
            super(name, style);
        }
        public static SampleLayout newInstance(){
            return new SampleLayout("custConv", "custConv");
        }

        @Override
        public void format(LogEvent event, StringBuilder stringBuilder) {
           //replace the %myMsg by XXXXX if sensitive           
           if (sensitive()){
               stringBuilder.append("XXXX");}
           else {
            stringBuilder.append(event.getMessage().getFormattedMessage());}            
        }   
    }
```

the CustomConfiguration class is responsable for creating the configuration of log4j and the line 9 where 'builder.setPackages("my.log4j.pluggins")' is important in order to scan that package and pick up the converter pluggin wich is SampleLayout. 
the second class will be responsible for formatting the new key '%myMsg' in the pattern that contains my sensitive message, this Converter class checks if that message is sensitive and actes accordingly.

Before you start logging you should configure your log4j like this

```
ConfigurationFactory.setConfigurationFactory(new CustomConfigurationFactory());
```